# how to call onSearchRequested when pressing magnifying glass

Tags: android, search

I'm using a `searchView` and try to pass some data when someone invokes a search. So i overrode the `onSearchReqested` method. The problem is, this method isn't called when someone types in the `SearchView` and presses the magnifying glass on the keyboard. Instead the result activity is started.

How can i call the `onSearchRequested` method prior starting the result activity when someone presses the magnifying glass.

i tried this two but it didnt work.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION) {
        onSearchRequested();
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

adding a listener to the searchview didn't work either

```
searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onSearchRequested();

    }
});
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

setOnQueryTextListerner finally worked

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        onSearchRequested();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
});
```